# I can't login to github by git CMD

Tags: git, authentication

When I try to push at my github, It send me a message:

```
"remote: Repository not found".
```

I think there is something wrong with my account, so I logout from github. (by delete Windows Credential and add it again)

And now, I try to push at my github again, It told me to enter a password. But I can't login - literally I can't type it.
There is no problem when I try to type command. Only the password isn't entered.

Does anybody know how can I solve this problem, at least a way to login to git by git CMD?

Comment: I may not be understanding correctly, but password entries into shells never display the character. Type the password in, press enter, and it should work.

Comment: Please show your exact steps (either commands if git via cmdline, or what you did on the GUI) leading up to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is not displayed as you type for security reasons. Try entering your password and hitting enter.